# Deploying Laravel and Nuxt.js application. Combine them, or deploy separately?

Tags: php, laravel, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I have been developing a website that uses Laravel (v6) on the backend, and Nuxt.js (v2) on the frontend. The idea was for laravel to act as an api & oauth2 server, that also server side rendered the Nuxt.js app. From my research, it seemed like this was not only a common route, but not too much hassle to implement.

While developing, I have kept the backend and frontend as completely separate projects with their own git repos and all that jazz. This is my first time deploying/developing a project like this, where there are two completely applications for the backend and frontend, so all this is very new and a little challenging at times. Now when it came time to deploy them, I always imagined that I would somehow merge the projects and that I would be able to setup Laravel to server side render the Nuxt.js app. However, I am now at that stage and trying to merge them with great difficulty.

Currently I am using the "laravel-nuxt" composer package and "laravel-nuxt" npm package in an attempt to connect the projects in one repo. However, I am having difficulty doing this. I've searched far and wide for a good resource on this process and have yet to find one that explains the process thoroughly. I even purchased a course on Udemy on the topic only to find out they didn't merge the projects! They deployed Nuxt to firebase and didn't even cover how the deployment of laravel.

Anyway, this is my question(s): should or could I keep the projects separate and have 2 completely separate deployments? Or rather, if I keep them separate, how do I deploy nuxt in a way that still gets server side rendered? To me it doesn't matter if they are separate or together, but the most important part is that the nuxt app utlitlizes SSR (server side rendering) for SEO purposes. So am I on the right track? Should I keep these projects separate or should I continue trying to merge them?

Sorry if this is unclear, I am rather frustrated and kind of losing my mind. I would really appreciate any feedback or point in the right direction. Thank you for your time in reading this, and I otherwise hope you have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently developed something with a similar structure, Nuxt.js frontend and Directus CMS as backend.

I kept backend and frontend separated repositories and also deployed both separately. The reason why I decided to do it that way was because both need different packages on the server side and use different eco systems.
Frontend needs only Node.js backend needs a webserver, database and PHP. I think this should not be mixed.

For backend I used my existing server where I already have stuff running like Nextcloud or a blog behind a nginx webserver.

For frontend I used Dokku which I can only recommend for deploying Node.js apps. Nuxt.js has instructions on how to deploy to it.

Most important for you is that SSR is done by Nuxt.js, you don't need a separate webserver for that. Just build it and use `npm start`. Depending on your installation/deployment you have to use nginx as proxy to avoid calling the app with a port number. Another thing that Dokku does for me automatically, if the app respects the PORT environment variable.